# Is it possible to use return-from inside a lambda function

Tags: lambda, common-lisp

I got a list of lists and I want to remove a certain kind of those list. Therefore I would use a remove-if-not with a lambda expression. But I might not need to go through all elements of a list to determine if it should be erased or not, as a conclusion a return-from is needed. But how can I apply one in an anonymous lambda function?

```
(defvar *listlist* (list (list 1 2 3) (list 3 4 5) (list 5 6 7) (list 7 8 9)))

(remove-if-not #'(lambda (arg)
                   (dolist (x arg)
                     (when (= x 3)
                       (return-from lambda t)))
                   nil)
               *listlist*)
```

Another thing, bothering me is the possible use of a mapcar instead of dolist, but then my problem gets even worse, as I now would have to return-from two lambda functions.

Comment: If you use alambda on the outer lambda, and lambda on the inner, you can return-from self; checkout mapc for the inner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dolist` establishes an implicit block, so you can use `return`.  Read more [here](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_dolist.htm).  Also, you can wrap `dolist` in explicit `block` so you can use `return-from`.

Comment: the block hint was a perfect fit, thank you I wrapped a block around the hole form of the lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Graham's [alambda](http://www.bookshelf.jp/texi/onlisp/onlisp_15.html) (instead of lambda; just add the 'a' at the front), in cases where you don't happen to have a dolist block to return from:

```
(remove-if-not 
  (alambda (arg)
    (dolist (x arg)
      (when (= x 3)
        (return-from self t))
      nil))
  *listlist*)
```

This works for the general case, where you are coding away, and writing a lambda function, and then you happen to need the lambda named so that you can return-from it. At this point, just add an 'a' to the lambda, and return-from self.